# Can i use fat-free framework to develop Action Domain Responder app

Tags: fat-free-framework

hi i need to know if is possible develop a webApp following Action Domain Responder architecture with fat-free framemwork.
i have used it to do MCV webAPP but i don't sure is the framwork framework to do and APP with Action Domain Responder architecture.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can build pretty much every architecture you want with fat-free, since it only is a microframework at its core, but YOU have to build it by yourself as fat-free is not dictating any structure. I've once build a RMR like architecture for fun with it, so yes you can if you know how to. ADR seems to me like another  term for Domain-Driven-Design, which is a good choice. Good luck ;)